# How to disable/hide a button as soon as clicked in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

We are noticing that in our Blazor server-side application, users are able to click a button more than once unintentionally. How can I prevent this using options available in Blazor framework?

Anything as simple as changing the text of the button to "processing..." as soon as they click the button will suffice our requirements but I am not sure how to achieve this. Handler for click event takes few seconds to process.

Any pointers?

Comment: I've tried to click a button more than once, but to no avail... It's amazing... not the very fact that your users can click more than once, just at their leisure, but the very fact that you folks have noticed this cryptic phenomena

Comment: @biostat: What does the Handler look like, is it async or not?

Comment: "Handler for click event takes few seconds to process." So what ? Let them take their time. You seem to have failed to understand the  processing flow: The issue is not how much time does it take for the event handler to execute, but the span of time elapsing immediately after clicking the button and encountering the first await operator which yields control to the calling code that proceed with re rendering of the component, and thus disabling the button. This takes a fraction of a second. No human hand can elicit a second click before the button is disabled.

Comment: "async or not", not relevant. What are you striving at ?

Comment: my issue is resolved and i understood the concept so let's close this thread. As Henk guessed I had several synchronous operations before the actual await statement which caused delay in handing the control back to calling code. I learned from my mistake.

Answer (score 15):

```
<button class="btn" disabled="@isTaskRunning" @onclick="DispatchTask">Click me</button>
```

This works best with an `async Task` handler method, as

```
async Task DispatchTask()   // avoid async void
{
    isTaskRunning = true;
    await Task.Delay(1);    // don't rely on DoLongWork() executing async
    await DoLongWork();

    isTaskRunning = false;
    // StateHasChanged();  // only needed in an async void
}
```

Suppose the DoWork() method looks like

```
async Task DoLongWork()
{
    Thread.Sleep(6000);   // synchronous
}
```

Then it executes synchronously, despite the `async`. The `Task.Delay(1)` remedies that.

Comment: await Task.Delay(1) did a whole world of difference. I am unable to click more than once, so, does that mean that awaitable method is performing some sort of synchronous operation? Can you please explain what does introducing delay do behind the scenes?

Comment: It does an implict StateHasChanged() and allow the Render engine to run.

Comment: "allow the GUI to catch up", what in the world does that mean ? Care to explain how calling await Task.Delay(1) makes any difference. Whether you use it or not, the yielding of control to the calling code that continues to re-render the component is taken place immediately after the first await operator is encountered. await DoLongWork(); is enough. what if you call Task.Delay(100000000). Will that make the re-rendering longer ;)

Comment: It "did a whole world of difference".

Comment: @biostat Same here. I must use `Task.Delay(1)` to show a "spinner" button while the work happens. It feels like a hack but I can't see another way. The `Task.Delay(1)` is actually 15 milliseconds on Windows and because the method is `async`, the UI is free and has time in that 15 ms to update the spinner button.

And I need the `await Taks.Delay(1)` because I need at least one `await` to make the method `async`. Everything I'm calling is synchronous.

Comment: This doesn't disable the button immediately - only after the server receives the request and the client receives the response. You can still click the button multiple times, especially if you have a slow connection.,

Comment: @neme - on a normal connection you'd have to click very fast, inside ~2ms. This is not using http.

Answer (score 8):

You likely have one of two problems or both:

1. Latency is an issue. Make sure you are hosting your application with Web Sockets enabled. The setting is dependent on the host, ex: Azure App Servers has a simple on/off knob for Web Sockets under settings. See the very last step in this blog post http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4349/Deploying-A-Server-Side-Blazor-Application-To-Azure.aspx
2. You have a long running task.

For a long running task you can try the following solution. I have not tested it, mileage may vary.

```
<button disabled=@IsTaskRunning @onclick="DispatchTask">Submit</button>

@code {

    bool IsTaskRunning = false;

    async void DispatchTask()
    {
        IsTaskRunning = true;

        await DoLongWork();

        IsTaskRunning = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    Task DoLongWork()
    {
        return Task.Delay(6000);
    }

}
```

Comment: second option did not help (still able to click multiple times). am looking into first option.

Comment: Updated my answer with a blog resource.

Comment: The `async void` is dangerous and unnecessary. Blazor accepts `async Task` habdlers.

Comment: async void can cause unhandled exceptions to "get lost". However, this is just a rough example and not meant to be used as-is. I wouldn't advise anyone to name a method DoLongWork either.

Also, async void is actually acceptable (not my pref) in Blazor. See the documentation at Blazor.net Microsoft uses it as well.

Comment: Add `StateHasChanged()` just after `IsTaskRunning = true` otherwise you're setting the variable but not refreshing the UI to pay attention to it.

Comment: Microsoft's doc uses an `async void` example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/azure-active-directory-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorization-configuration). Also, @ataraxia I've found that `StateHasChanged()` does not always update the UI. It notifies the UI but does not seem to guarantee it will get refreshed.

Comment: What if you have a slow internet connection, e.g. on a WiFi? This still won't disable the button immediately - only after the server receives the event and the client receives the response. Users can still click the button multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

How about a generic solution? SpinnerButton

It could easily be edited to use a standard button. [Generate a SVG animation here.](https://loading.io/)

(both Radzen and Loading.io are free)

```
<RadzenButton Text="@(IsProcessing ? null : Text)" Image="@(IsProcessing ? Spinner : null)" Disabled="@IsProcessing" @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public string Spinner { get; set; } = "/images/spinner-button.svg";

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public IDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    public bool IsProcessing { get; private set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnSubmit { get; set; }

    public async Task FormSubmitAsync()
    {
        if (IsProcessing) { return; }

        IsProcessing = true;
        try
        {
            await OnSubmit.InvokeAsync(null);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsProcessing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Use like this

```
<EditForm OnValidSubmit="@SubmitAsync">
    <SpinnerButton @ref="ButtonRef" style="width:150px" Text="Login" 
        ButtonType="@((Radzen.ButtonType)ButtonType.Submit)" 
        ButtonStyle="@((Radzen.ButtonStyle)ButtonStyle.Primary)"
        OnSubmit="LogInAsync" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    public SpinnerButton? ButtonRef { get; set; }
    public async Task SubmitAsync() => await ButtonRef!.FormSubmitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    public async Task LogInAsync()
    {
        // Get stuff done!
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't disable the button immediately - only after the server receives the request and the client receives the response. You can still click the button multiple times, especially if you have a slow connection.

Answer (score -2):

```
private Dictionary<string, string> control = new Dictionary<string, string>();

function click(){
    lock (control)
        {
            if (!control.ContainsKey("click"))
            {
            control.Add("click", "executing");
            }
            else
            {
            if (control["click"] == "executing")
            {
                //Double click detected
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                control["click"] = "executing";
            }
            }
        }


//Do usual stuffs here


    lock (control)
    {
        control["click"] = "";
    }
```

}