Web app - How can I handle events from a user synchronously?
I have a Blazor Interactive Server app. On several of my pages I have a component where the user can register for an event. There are 4 buttons (No, Undecided, Interested, Attending). When they click the button, that fires an event that reads 2 records from the DB, updates them with the signup status, and saves them.
Users are quickly clicking several buttons (no idea why). The end result is I am getting a DbUpdateConcurrencyException because it reads the records in the several event handler calls, updates them, then goes to save them and all after the first throw a DbUpdateConcurrencyException.
Is there a way to force this event handler, for each session, to be processed synchronously? The records involved are user records so there is no conflict across sessions unless a user connects via 2 browsers and clicks at the same time - in which case tough.
Update: My QA tester has verified that it was running slow for him (due to his internet connection) and so he was clicking several times thinking it didn’t register the first time.

Can you clarify that fires an event.  Is that a standard C# event [fire and forget] or a Blazor EventCallBack [returns a Task].

@MrCakaShaunCurtis it’s an EventCallBack - called when. DxButton is clicked.

Why not disable (just) the button during the handling? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204245/60761

My answer is the same as the others - disable the buttons.  As in the answer and Henk's correction.,

Just another option here, you could lock the buttons from being pressed once one has been pressed. Something like the following:
<button @onclick="Undecided" disabled="isSaving">Undecided</button>
<button @onclick="Interested" disabled="isSaving">Interested</button>
// etc

private bool isSaving;

private async Task Undecided()
{
   isSaving = true;
   StateHasChanged();

   // do stuff

   isSaving = false;
}

private async Task Interested()
{
   isSaving = true;   
   StateHasChanged();

   // do stuff

   isSaving = false;
}

// etc

This way you can stay async and hopefully avoid the concurrency issue.

You don't need StateHasChanged() but you may want to use a Delay(1) here. Depends on async // do stuff is.

It sounds like the issue here is actually to do with the way your database is wired up in the component. Are you injecting a DbContext into your component, and then using the same instance throughout the component?
If so, this will be the cause of the issue.
In Blazor, injected services are scoped to the lifetime of the circuit (as opposed to the lifetime of the request like in more traditional web applications). DbContexts will not allow concurrent work on the same instance you see.
Microsoft's recommendations are that you should have a DbContext instance per action (instead of a common instance for the component).
The way to achieve this is to inject a DbContextFactory into the component, and then you can create instances easily.
@inject IDbContextFactory<ContactContext> DbFactory

private async Task Undecided()
{
   // create a DbContext that is scoped to just this action
   using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();

   // do DB stuff here

   await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

private async Task Interested()
{
   using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();

   // do DB stuff here

   await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

You can read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0#new-dbcontext-instances
I realise that this answers your question in a different way. You could force synchronous actions instead, but sub-optimal.

I already do as you list above. I create the DbContext within each event handler. The problem is the code in that event handler, each with their own DbContext, read the record, set properties in the record, and then write it. TIA

Could you post some of that code do you think? It would be useful to see.
